# Wordpress menu dissapear when I add a parameter to custom post archive

Tags: plugins, themes

If I view the page  **/custom_archive/** -> **the menu shows up correctly**

But if I view the page **/custom_archive/?custom_param=1** **only the Homepage** item from the menu **shows up.**

This looks like there is a filter somewhere that is doing something... or there is a bug

Here is how I get my items on the archive page :

```
    $menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menuID = $menuLocations['my_menu_location']; 
    $primaryNav = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuID);
    // this code runs on archive page
```

So why does sometimes work and sometimes not, and how I can make this always return the same menu?

I'm guessing there is a filter out there in get_posts via wp_get_nav_menu_items that is causing this behavior. Most likely from a plugin.

Registering the menu:

```
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'flst' ),
            'top_menu_2' => esc_html__( 'Top Menu 2', 'flst' ),
        )
    ); // executed via add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_function_setup' );
```

Comment: What parameter are you trying to use? WordPress reserves a number of parameters for its own use.

Comment: also can you expand the code you've shared? What are you doing with the `$primaryNav` variable?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I'm using y1=2022 I know for sure that if I use year(a reserved parameter) the archive is generating a 404 page. So I'm 100% sure this is not the problem

Comment: @TomJNowell  $primaryNav normally return an array, but for me when I use param y1=2022 is returning an empty array

Comment: you'll need to share the part where you're registering the menus too, as well as details of when and where it and the code you've already shared runs. Use the edit links to update the question

Comment: @TomJNowell I added more details as you suggested

Comment: I don't think you've add enough to diagnose this, include the code you use to test this, as well as where in the theme you put the code ( filenames ). Also avoid censoring or making things generic as it hides important details. e.g. `custom_param` in your question should be edited to show the actual variable ( `y1`? ) And what does the URL parameter do and where is the code that uses it? It's likely the problem is in code you haven't shared, or code you don't consider to be related to this. Do you have `pre_get_posts` filters?